# Match in React.js always returing nothing

Tags: reactjs, string-matching

Inside my `Login` class I have this piece of code :

```
state={email:'',passwordHash:''};

onButtonClick = () =>{
    if(this.state.email==='' || this.state.passwordHash==='')
        return;
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
            console.log(this.responseText);
        }
    };
    request.open('GET', 'http://localhost:8080/login/'+this.state.email+'/'+this.state.passwordHash, true);
    request.send();
    if(String(request.responseText).match("true"))
    {
        console.log("Inside Match");
        window.location.href = '/home';
    }
};
```

And in the console I get this :

[image: javascript string matching problem]

As I'm getting `true` in the console, I should also get `Inside Match` in the console and then redirect, but that is not happening.

Can anyone help me with this problem ?

I have also tried `===` , `==` , single quote.

Comment: Isn't the `send` function asynchronous ? Does it accepts a callback function ?

Comment: @Treycos ,I'm new to javascript . I actually don't know ? What should I do now ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `onButtonClick` function should be like this :

```
onButtonClick = () =>{
    if(this.state.email==='' || this.state.passwordHash==='')
        return;
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
            if(String(request.responseText).match("true"))
            {
                console.log("Inside Match");
                window.location.href = '/home';
            }
        }
    };
    request.open('GET', 'http://localhost:8080/login/'+this.state.email+'/'+this.state.passwordHash, true);
    request.send();

};
```

So when it gets data in response, it will redirect to another page, or console log or whatever. But it should be done inside that `async` function `onreadystatechange`.